# Paths with PGF/TikZ, in and out of foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% CTC : center to center
% Distance is 2*sin(pi/3)
\def\ctc{1.7320508075688772cm}

% Draw an hexagon anywhere.
\def\hexagon#1{
    %\draw #1 +(0:1cm) \foreach \a in {60,120,...,300} { -- +(\a:1cm) } -- cycle;
    \fill[red] #1 circle (0.2cm);
}
% Draw a small hextile anywhere.
\def\hextile#1{
    \foreach \l in {1,2} {
        \foreach \a in {30,90,...,330} {
            \hexagon{#1 ++(\a:\l*\ctc)};
        }
        \foreach \a in {0,60,...,300} {
            \hexagon{#1 ++(\a:\l*3cm-3cm)};
        }
    }
}
\def\hextiles{
    \foreach \a in {0,120,240} {
        \hextile{(\a:6cm)};
    }
}

%\hextiles;
\hextile{(0:6cm)};
\hextile{(120:6cm)};
\hextile{(240:6cm)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am wondering why, oh why, calling `\hextiles` and `\hextile` three times don't give out the same result...

It seems linked with the way paths are handled, but I can't see how...

Comment: Can you please include a minimal and compilable document starting from `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`?

Comment: Just did it, but all was there already.

Comment: Please try to compile your example. There is no `\ctc` defined and hextile definition is missing a closing brace and no `\end{tizkpicture}` just by looking at it.

Comment: Updated, this is now a minimal pathological example

Comment: \hextiles and \hextile should use different macro names for there loops...

Comment: Incidentally, you don't need all those semi-colons.  Only the actual drawing commands (`\draw`, `\fill`, `\node`, `\path` and the like) need semi-colons.  All "wrapper" macros don't need them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you reuse the macro `\a` in your `\foreach` loops.  When you do

```
\def\hextiles{
    \foreach \a in {0,120,240} {
        \hextile{(\a:6cm)};
    }
}
```

Then `\hextile` is called with the argument *literally* `(\a:6cm)`.  This gets substituted in to the command wherever there is a `#1`.  Thus the result of `\hextile{(\a:6cm)}` is to insert the following into the stream:

```
\foreach \l in {1,2} {
        \foreach \a in {30,90,...,330} {
            \hexagon{(\a:6cm) ++(\a:\l*\ctc)}
        }
        \foreach \a in {0,60,...,300} {
            \hexagon{(\a:6cm) ++(\a:\l*3cm-3cm)}
        }
    }
```

So the `\a` which eventually gets used is **not** the `\a` of the outer loop, but the `\a` of the inner loop.  One solution is simply to change names:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% CTC : center to center
% Distance is 2*sin(pi/3)
\def\ctc{1.7320508075688772cm}

% Draw an hexagon anywhere.
\def\hexagon#1{
  \draw #1 +(0:1cm) \foreach \a in {60,120,...,300} { -- +(\a:1cm) } -- cycle;
    \fill[red] #1 circle (0.2cm);
}
% Draw a small hextile anywhere.
\def\hextile#1{
    \foreach \l in {1,2} {
        \foreach \a in {30,90,...,330} {
            \hexagon{#1 ++(\a:\l*\ctc)}
        }
        \foreach \a in {0,60,...,300} {
            \hexagon{#1 ++(\a:\l*3cm-3cm)}
        }
    }
}
\def\hextiles{
    \foreach \b in {0,120,240} {
        \hextile{(\b:6cm)}
    }
}

\hextiles
%\hextile{(0:6cm)};
%\hextile{(120:6cm)};
%\hextile{(240:6cm)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

A more robust solution would be to ensure that `\a` is not passed literally but its value is used.  The best method of doing this depends a bit on what situations you're going to be using these macros in.

Comment: Thank you, I missed it. I read about a similar concern when defining `\a1` and `\a2` in imbricated foreach loops.